# i can only call a function once to compare 2 numbers using pointers

Tags: c, pointers, function-pointers

i have to compare 2 numbers using pointers but i can only call my function one time to get the number then i have to find the largest number from the 2. then I have to display which one was largest.I am having a hard time beacause I dont know where I went Wrong  because the  second number it always says is larger when I enter the larger one first. Can someone help? Here is what I tried.

```
#include <stdio.h>


        void getnumbers(float*,float*);
        float findlargest(float*,float*);
        void displaylargest(float);  

            int main ()
        {
              float num;
              float num2;
              float largest;

              getnumbers(&num,&num2);

              largest=findlargest(&num,&num2);
              displaylargest(largest);  

return 0;
}

          void getnumbers(float*num,float*num2)
        {

               printf("Enter a number\n");
               scanf("%f",num);

               printf("Enter a number\n");
               scanf("%f",num2);


            }

             float findlargest(float*numptr,float*num2ptr)
         {


            if (*numptr>*num2ptr) {
               return *numptr;
} 
else {
    return *num2ptr;
}
 }

 void displaylargest(float largest)
{
   printf("\nthe largest is %f ",largest);

 }
```

Comment: Change API from `float getnumbers();` to `void getnumbers(float *, float *);`

Comment: Also `scanf("%2f",` --> `scanf("%f",`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets start with `getNumbers()`:
To get a function to return more than one value, you can pass parameters by reference. [This post](https://denniskubes.com/2012/08/20/is-c-pass-by-value-or-reference/) has a good explanation of passing parameters by reference.

> When we pass-by-value we are passing a copy of the variable to a function. When we pass-by-reference we are passing an alias of the variable to a function.

Where the alias is a pointer to the memory location of `num` or `num2` declared  in `main()` (see function below). This allows you to change their value inside the function  the variables were passed to.

```
void getnumbers(float *num, float *num2)//pass by ref to get two numbers
{
    printf("Enter a number\n");
    scanf("%f",num);//"%2f" is not something you would do

    printf("Enter a number\n");
    scanf("%f",num2);//assign to num2, not num
}
```

Now `findLargest()` really does not need to be taking pointers as parameters, but it can if the assignment requires. You would only do that if you intend to **change** their value. If you need to only **use** the value, you just pass by value:

```
//much more concise and does the exact same thing!
//Normally wouldn't use pointers here, but it is a requirement for the assignment
float findlargest(float *num, float *num2)
{
    return *num > *num2 ? *num : *num2;
}
```

Now your main becomes:

```
int main ()
{
    float num = 0;//always a good idea to initialize variables!
    float num2 = 0;
    float largest = 0;

    getnumbers(&num, &num2);//pass by reference

    largest = findlargest(&num, &num2);//pass by value

    displaylargest(largest);  

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @andreanobles, I edited my answer so that `findLargest()` takes pointers as arguments. Hope it helps.

Comment: thank you so much for your help i used    float findlargest(float*numptr,float*num2ptr)
             {
                 

                if (*numptr>*num2ptr) {
                   return *numptr;
    } 
    else {
        return *num2ptr;
    }   instead because  the other was for c+

Comment: You're welcome @andreanobles! Actually what you're commenting on is quite a common technique used by programmers. It is called a [ternary operator](https://www.sitesbay.com/cprogramming/c-ternary-operator), and it is ubiquitous in `C`, `C++`, `C#` and many other languages. It is basically a shorthand for one liner `if/else`, where a case like above is a perfect application. That being said, it is a good idea to not use things your prof hasn't taught you yet, just FYI.

Answer (score 1):

i believe it is because you are using the same variable to enter a number 

i.e. num 2 doesn't have a value

```
void getNumbers(float *num1, float *num2){
  printf("Enter a number\n");
  scanf("%2f", num1);
  printf("Enter a number\n");
  scanf("%2f", num2);
}
```

this passes the num1 and num2 variable by "**call by reference**" and allows you to directly modify the value stored in the pointer num1 and num2, so you don't have to return any value too.

then when you compare it should compare two values you enter in now.

Comment: There is no such thing as "pass by reference" in C. Everything is pass by value. You are passing the *value* of the address of `num` to `scanf`.

Answer (score 0):

You are never assigning `num2` in main. Your `getnumbers` function asks the user for two numbers and only returns one of them. I don't know why you have to use pointers for your `getlargest` function -- that makes no sense -- but if those are your requirements, then okay.

To fix your problems, rewrite `getnumbers` to take in two pointers to `float` where you will then pass to `scanf`.

Answer (score 0):

Your **main ()** function inside the **num2** is not assigned, because the initial **num2** is **0**, so you get the result is always **num2** the smallest。

Your **getnumbers ()** also has an error, it can only return the last keyboard input value。

Comment: There is no such default initialization to 0 in C. In fact, the OP reports the *opposite* behavior: *" the second number it always says is larger when I enter the larger one first*"

Answer (score 0):

bie jiao yin yu.

your function "getnumbers" only return one value,num2 Uninitialized.

There are 2 solution:

(1)add
    `num2 = getnumbers();`
and delete

```
printf("Enter a number\n");
scanf("%2f",&num);
```

(2)modify your function

```
getnumbers(&num, &num2);

void getnumbers(float *num1,float *num2) {
   printf("Enter a number\n");
   scanf("%f",num1);
   printf("Enter a number\n");
   scanf("%f",num2);
}
```

Comment: Your function doesn't return anything. You marked it to return `float`.